# Swing layouts dependency on container

Tags: java, swing, grouplayout

Why does a GroupLayout require a Container as an argument to the constructor, while a BorderLayout does not?

I am not sure what information the Container object adds and why BorderLayout doesn't need that information.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to see this is to look at the source.  The `GroupLayout` constructor saves the `Component` (not the Container, as you said) into a field named `host`.  This field is then used in these methods:

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout#adjustSize
javax.swing.GroupLayout#checkParent
javax.swing.GroupLayout#getComponentInfo
javax.swing.GroupLayout#invalidateHost
javax.swing.GroupLayout#isLeftToRight
javax.swing.GroupLayout#replace
javax.swing.GroupLayout.AutoPreferredGapSpring#calculatePadding
javax.swing.GroupLayout.ContainerAutoPreferredGapSpring#calculatePadding
javax.swing.GroupLayout.ContainerAutoPreferredGapSpring#updateSize
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PreferredGapSpring#getPadding
```

Each of these methods require knowing who the `Component` is.  For example, `adjustSize` uses the insets of the `Component` to calculate the size.